# how to delay the return in React until fetch is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am using React js and want to render data that I got it from API using Fetch .
the problem is I can't display the fetch results because the Return scope of React excute befor the fetch method done!!
Please any help of how I can solve this ???

this is a part of the function that do the Fetch :

```
initFourSquare = () => {
       return fetch(FourSquareAPI)
           .then(data => {
             return data.json()
           })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message)
          })
    };
```

this is the render part of react where I called the function (initFourSquare)

```
  render() {

     var info = []
     this.initFourSquare().then(response => {
            info = response.response.venues
              console.log(info) //the result is appear here
          })
      setTimeout(function(){ console.log(info[0].name) }, 1000);//the result is appear here

    return (
            <div>
              <h1>{info}</h1> // it display nothing !!!
            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The key here is that you should update the component's state whenever the asynchronous call is done. Note that loading asynchronous content is not really different from handling any other event, the only difference is that "you" (the program) initiated the fetch which ultimately lead to the event of the content being loaded. What should trigger loading the content is not the `render`, but the `mounting` of the component. Rendering the component means: "representing it's current state to the view".

Comment: thank you very much for your usefull information, yes my problem was  forgot call the state to update the render

Answer (score 0):

Any API/asynchronous call shouldn't be made in render function instead, you should do that in componentDidMount function if it is to be done once which seems to be your case and set the response in state which you can use in render. Make sure that you either initialise the state correctly or provide a conditional check for existence before using state variable

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
       info: []
   }
   componentDidMount() {
     var info = []
     this.initFourSquare().then(response => {
          info = response.response.venues
          this.setState({info})
     })

   }
   initFourSquare = () => {
       return fetch(FourSquareAPI)
           .then(data => {
             return data.json()
           })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message)
          })
   };
   render() {
    const { info } = this.state;
    return (
            <div>
              <h1>{info}</h1>
            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I changed my code as your advice but still got an empty array at the Return scope of render !!

Comment: Are you calling setState which will trigger a re-render once data is available

Comment: Yes that is the solution, I forgot call the state to update the render, thank you very much